# Hide all notifications when screen sharing

Tags: notifications, screen-sharing

I'd like to never show ANY notifications if I'm currently screen sharing to prevent those awkward moments where I forget to disable them manually and run the risk of someone IM'ing me something inappropriate. Notifications should be automatically disabled when I start screen sharing and automatically re-enabled when I stop.

Is this possible at all? Even if it requires some development?

Comment: +100 for the need.  I actually have a separate user for this reason, but that creates even more issues than it solves.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Muzzleapp for this. It silences all notifications as you turn on screen sharing. Download it from the official website: https://muzzleapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the OS you're using so for this answer I'm using 10.12.5.
[Source](https://rothmanshore.com/2014/07/29/shortcut-getting-a-mac-to-behave-during-presentations-and-conference-calls/).

You can <kbd>option</kbd>+click on the 3 lines for Notification Center in the menu bar:[image]

This will silence any notifications that use the Apple system for notifications.  To put notifications back to normal, <kbd>option</kbd>+click again.

This doesn't silence any notifications that **don't** use Apple's system.  To silence those, you'll need to turn them off at the application-level.

Comment: That's useful but it doesn't really answer the question. The problem is that people often just forget to turn off notifications and will only be reminded when it's too late (i.e., once the embarrassing notification has already popped up for everyone to see).

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  You asked how to stop all notifications when screensharing.  By doing this before you start a screenshare, all notifications will be disabled if the application sending the notification uses the standard Apple system.  Perhaps you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/284709/edit) your question to included more details about what you're looking for?

Comment: I meant how to do it automatically whenever​ screen sharing begins. I updated the question.